# Hibernate + jcache + ehcache integration not woking

Tags: hibernate, second-level-cache, jcache, ehcache-3

In my application I want to enable second level cache by using `Hibernate 5.4` and `EHCache 3.7` but I am getting this error

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider: Provider org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider could not be instantiated
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

The dependencies I am using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the config for second level cache:

```
properties.setProperty(Environment.USE_QUERY_CACHE, "true");
properties.setProperty(Environment.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, "jcache");
```

Comment: Solved. The problem was I was using an incorrect jvm version

Comment: Hi , I am facing the same problem , how do you solve it ? Thanks.

Comment: Ensure you are using at least jvm 1.8